# CentOS - how to make sure IPv6 is supported?

Tags: linux, centos, ipv6, apple, itunes

When i dig to my server i get following, clearly showing not IPv6 supported. As a result Apple ([reference](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/147579#147579)) verification team refusing my apps/softwares to be published because IPv6 is not supported in my server.

How can i make it fixed?

```
$ dig +nocmd +nostats turn.myserver.com AAAA
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21625
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;turn.myserver.com. IN  AAAA
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a quad-a record to your DNS server's zone file.

You need to tell us which DNS server software you are running.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:**

We want AAAA in our DNS manager

```
A             = IPv4 = 8.8.8.8
AAAA = Quad-A = IPv6 = ugly:awkward:ipv6:8888
```

**Step 1:** [reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-ipv6-for-digitalocean-droplets#enabling-ipv6-on-an-existing-droplet)

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=primary_ipv6_address<<<<</64
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=ipv6_gateway<<<<
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
```

**Step 2:**

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network
# this will start IPv6 on system boot
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
```

**Step 3:**

```
ip -6 addr
ping6 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

**TEST:**

```
$ dig +nocmd +nostats turn.myserver.com AAAA
```

Comment: Answers are meant only for answers to the question. To add additional information to your question, edit the question instead.